# How do I flatten nested list from JSON object?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, json-normalize

I've exported fitbit sleep data and got a json file with nested variables + dict. I would like to convert the json file to a csv file that will display all "regular" variables, e.g. "dateOfSleep" but also the nested variables, e.g. "deep" & "wake" with all dictionary information.

I tried json_normalize; but I can only make it work for the first nested variables, e.g. "levels". Anybody has an idea?

Much appreciated.

```
[{
  "logId" : 32072056107,
  "dateOfSleep" : "2021-05-08",
  "startTime" : "2021-05-07T23:22:00.000",
  "endTime" : "2021-05-08T08:05:30.000",
  "duration" : 31380000,
  "minutesToFallAsleep" : 0,
  "minutesAsleep" : 468,
  "minutesAwake" : 55,
  "minutesAfterWakeup" : 0,
  "timeInBed" : 523,
  "efficiency" : 93,
  "type" : "stages",
  "infoCode" : 0,
  "levels" : {
    "summary" : {
      "deep" : {
        "count" : 5,
        "minutes" : 85,
        "thirtyDayAvgMinutes" : 68
      },
      "wake" : {
        "count" : 30,
        "minutes" : 55,
        "thirtyDayAvgMinutes" : 56
      },
      "light" : {
        "count" : 30,
        "minutes" : 267,
        "thirtyDayAvgMinutes" : 235
      },
      "rem" : {
        "count" : 10,
        "minutes" : 116,
        "thirtyDayAvgMinutes" : 94
      }
    },
.....
```

Comment: `pd.json_normalize` works at least for the data you've provided here

Comment: `json_normalize` works fine for your data sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.json_normalize`, all nested levels are flatten and join with dots (by default):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('data.json') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
    df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         logId dateOfSleep                startTime  ... levels.summary.rem.count  levels.summary.rem.minutes  levels.summary.rem.thirtyDayAvgMinutes
0  32072056107  2021-05-08  2021-05-07T23:22:00.000  ...                       10                         116                                      94

[1 rows x 25 columns]
```

Content of `data.json`:

```
[{
  "logId" : 32072056107,
  "dateOfSleep" : "2021-05-08",
  "startTime" : "2021-05-07T23:22:00.000",
  "endTime" : "2021-05-08T08:05:30.000",
  "duration" : 31380000,
  "minutesToFallAsleep" : 0,
  "minutesAsleep" : 468,
  "minutesAwake" : 55,
  "minutesAfterWakeup" : 0,
  "timeInBed" : 523,
  "efficiency" : 93,
  "type" : "stages",
  "infoCode" : 0,
  "levels" : {
    "summary" : {
      "deep" : {
        "count" : 5,
        "minutes" : 85,
        "thirtyDayAvgMinutes" : 68
      },
      "wake" : {
        "count" : 30,
        "minutes" : 55,
        "thirtyDayAvgMinutes" : 56
      },
      "light" : {
        "count" : 30,
        "minutes" : 267,
        "thirtyDayAvgMinutes" : 235
      },
      "rem" : {
        "count" : 10,
        "minutes" : 116,
        "thirtyDayAvgMinutes" : 94
      }
    }
  }
}]
```